# SQL query not returning correct output

Tags: sql

I have to write a SQL query according to the description given in the picture below.

My query shown here does not work. Please help, how to write correct query?

My query:

```
select 
    BUYER_ID, sum(price)
from
    house h 
join 
    price p using(HOUSE_ID)
group by 
    BUYER_ID
having 
    sum(price) >= 100;
```

Question:

[image]

Comment: Please paste the data in instead of using an image.

Comment: Please mention the db name. This will increase chance to get accurate answers.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. You just need to add the second criteria -- the owner has more than one house -- in the `HAVING` clause. Count the distinct `house_id`s.

```
SELECT h.buyer_id,
       sum(p.price) total_worth
       FROM house h
            INNER JOIN price p
                       USING (house_id)
       GROUP BY h.buyer_id
       HAVING sum(p.price) >= 100
              AND count(DISTINCT h.house_id) > 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 conditions that needs to be satisfied: the House prices should be at least 100M and the no. of houses should be more than 1

SELECT h.BUYER_ID, SUM(p.PRICE) FROM house AS h LEFT JOIN price AS p ON h. HOUSE_ID=p.HOUSE_ID GROUP BY h.HOUSE_ID HAVING SUM(p.PRICE)>99 AND COUNT(p.HOUSE_ID)>1

Answer (score -1):

Simply add the second condition to your `having` clause.

Your SQL:

```
select BUYER_ID, sum(price)
from house h join price p using(HOUSE_ID)
group by BUYER_ID
having sum(price) >= 100;
```

Updated SQL:

```
select BUYER_ID, sum(price)
from house h join price p using(HOUSE_ID)
group by BUYER_ID
having sum(price) >= 100
and count(BUYER_ID) > 1;
```

### ** Edit to show SQLFiddle

Not sure why I got downvoted when clearly SQLFiddle outputs OP's question

[SQLFiddler Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64e454/1)

Comment: Please enlighten me on why my answer was downvoted so that I can correct it.